# php/sql code not inserting array into sql table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have some code as shown below which inserts some data into an sql table.  The array that I am trying to enter is working properly, I have also put an extra check before the insert code which displays the array correctly `$array_author[$i]`

I really don't understand why the insert code to the `product_rating` table is not working correctly.

```
// Firstly the Author data is used to make a new user in the users table.
for($i = 0; $i<count($array_review); $i++){
  $queryInsertUser=mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO `users` 
  (`Name`, `DOB`, `Sex`, `Email`, `Address`, `AddedDate`, `AddedFrom`,`Crawler`) 
  VALUES ('$array_author[$i]', '$dob', '$sex', '$email', '$address', NOW(), '$http_referrer',2)");

// Review and rating data is inserted into the product_rating table.  The user created from the author data
//is then inserted into the product_rating table.
  $selectuser = mysqli_query($link, " SELECT `UserID` FROM `users` ORDER BY `UserID` DESC LIMIT 1 ");
  while ($rowGetDetails = mysqli_fetch_array($selectuser)){
    echo '<br>';
    echo $array_review[$i];
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO product_rating (ProductID,Rating,AddedDate,Comment,AddedBy,AddedFrom,crawler) 
    VALUES ('$ProductID','$array_rating2[$i]',NOW(),'$array_review[$i]','$UserID','".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."','2')";
    $insertcomment = mysqli_query($link, $sql2);
    }
  }
```

This code inserts correctly in the first table (`users`).
I have tried this code without the `$array_author[$i]` and a new record is correctly inserted in the `product_rating` table.

Sorry `array_author` is defined higher up in the code.  I can include the `array_author` , `array_rating2` and `array_review` being filled below:

```
$array_author = array();
$pos = -1;
while(FALSE != $pos = strpos($str_test, "<span itemprop=\"author\">",$pos+1)) {
    $pos2 = substr($str_test, $pos+24);       
    $pos3 = strpos($pos2, "</span>");
    $author= substr($pos2, 0, $pos3);
    $author=ltrim ($author);       
    $author=rtrim ($author);
    $array_author[ ] = $author;
    }

$array_review = array();
$pos3 = -1;
while (FALSE != $pos3 = strpos($str_test, "<span itemprop=\"description\">",$pos3 + 1)){ 
          $pos4= substr($str_test, $pos3+30);
          $pos5 = strpos($pos4, "</span>");
          $review= substr($pos4, 0, $pos5);   
          $review=ltrim ($review);       
          $review=rtrim ($review);
          $array_review[ ] = $review;
          }

$array_rating = array();
$pos3 = -1;
while (FALSE != $pos3 = strpos($str_test, "<span itemprop=\"ratingValue\">", $pos3 + 1)){
          $pos4= substr($str_test, $pos3+29);
          $pos5 = strpos($pos4, "</span>");
          $rating= substr($pos4, 0, $pos5);   
          $rating=ltrim ($rating);       
          $rating=rtrim ($rating);
          $array_rating[] = $rating;
          }
```

Comment: that's funny because you don't have an array_author

Comment: can include the declaration of those variables that you are using